# If $X$ has increments independent of $\mathcal F$, is $\Delta X_t$ independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $t>s$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-adapted $E$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ such that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $t\ge s\ge0$.

> Are we able to show that $\Delta X_t:=X_t-\lim_{r\to t-}X_r$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for alL $t>s\ge0$?

I would like to use the fact that if $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal A$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ such that $Y_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}Y$ almost surely and $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent of $\mathcal F$, then $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal F$.

Now, we can clearly take $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$. Then, $$\Delta X_t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\left(X_t-X_{t_n}\right)}_{=:\:Y_n}$$ and $Y_n$ is independent of $\mathcal F_{t_n}\supseteq\mathcal F_s$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. However, while this yields that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma(Y_n)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$, it doesn't necessarily yield (see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2896440/47771) that $\sigma(X_n,n\in\mathbb N)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma(Y_n)\right)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.

How can we solve this issue?